# Iterating over rows in pandas, shifting values to the right by one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, shift

I need to iterate over a dataframe to get the values from the first date to move to the next row and start with same first value. Importantly, I need the new inputs to stop at the column range and not overflow past day5 in the example below.

current output:

```
            day1  day2  day3  day4  day5
date                                    
2018-03-16   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
2018-03-17   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2018-03-18   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2018-03-19   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2018-03-20   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

desired output:

```
             day1  day2  day3  day4  day5
date                                    
2018-03-16   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
2018-03-17   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2018-03-18   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0
2018-03-19   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0
2018-03-20   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
```

sample code to iterate:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
columns_name = ['day1', 'day2', 'day3', 'day4', 'day5']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.T
df.columns = columns_name

dates = pd.date_range('2018-03-16', '2018-03-20').tolist()
dates_df = pd.DataFrame(dates)
dates_df.columns = ['date']

dfs = [df, dates_df]
combined = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
combined = combined.set_index(['date'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `numpy.triu_indices`

Slice the first row with triangle indices and assign

```
v = df.values
i, j = np.triu_indices(v.shape[1])
v[i, j] = v[0][j - i]
df

            day1  day2  day3  day4  day5
date                                    
2018-03-16   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
2018-03-17   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2018-03-18   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0
2018-03-19   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0
2018-03-20   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
```

---

If that happens not to work for you because `df.values` is a copy and not a view:

```
v = df.values
i, j = np.triu_indices(v.shape[1])
v[i, j] = v[0][j - i]
df.loc[:] = v
df

            day1  day2  day3  day4  day5
date                                    
2018-03-16   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
2018-03-17   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2018-03-18   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0
2018-03-19   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0
2018-03-20   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
```

---

## `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`

**NOT RECOMMENDED**
But still fun

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided

n = df.shape[1]
v = np.append([np.nan for _ in range(n - 1)], df.values[0])
s = v.strides[0]

df.loc[:] = strided(v[n - 1:], df.shape, (-s, s))

df

            day1  day2  day3  day4  day5
date                                    
2018-03-16   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
2018-03-17   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2018-03-18   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0   3.0
2018-03-19   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   2.0
2018-03-20   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
```